# Git rename detection of empty file

Tags: git, merge, file-rename

I recently hit a problem where an empty file was renamed differently in two branches but merged without a conflict being raised.

Steps to recreate are as follows.

1. Create an empty file.

   ```
   git init
   touch empty
   git add empty
   git commit -m "add empty file"
   ```
2. Rename it in the branch.

   ```
   git checkout -b branch
   git mv empty empty-in-branch
   git commit -m "empty -> empty-in-branch"
   ```
3. Rename it differently in the master.

   ```
   git checkout master
   git mv empty empty-in-master
   git commit -m "empty -> empty-in-master"
   ```
4. Merge branch into master.

   ```
   git merge --no-commit branch
   ```

This gives the message `Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested`.

`git status` shows just the new file `empty-in-branch`. But there is no deletion of `empty-in-master` so if we commit at this stage we'll get both files.

**I'd expect this to be flagged as a merge conflict that needed manual resolution (i.e. deciding which empty file to keep). That's what happens if the original file is non-empty.**

Is there something special about empty files that affects the rename detection? Are there any parameters I could add to the `git merge` that will get it to detect the conflict (e.g. tweaking the merge strategy)?

Comment: Interesting behavior for sure. Not sure the cause, but... Git stores files according to their contents. So two empty files would technically be considered the same. Because of the potential for a huge number of overlaps, it'd make sense to have some special logic here.

Comment: It certainly looks like there might be special handling for empty files. But Git already only stores one copy of each object based on its hash, so there's no real difference between lots of duplicated empty files and lots of duplicated non-empty files (i.e. no obvious need for special treatment of empty files).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empty files are no longer considered for renames on a recursive merge as of this commit: https://github.com/git/git/commit/4f7cb99ada26be5d86402a6e060f3ee16a672f16

Older versions of Git still report it as a conflict.

```
$ git --version
git version 1.7.9.5
# ... follow OP instructions to reproduce
$ git merge --no-commit branch
CONFLICT (rename/rename): Rename "empty"->"empty-in-master" in branch "HEAD" rename "empty"->"empty-in-branch" in "branch"
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
$ git status
# On branch master
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#   both deleted:       empty
#   added by them:      empty-in-branch
#   added by us:        empty-in-master
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Git doesn't implicitly track renames, so without the rename detection what ends up happening is Git just sees that both commits deleted the file `empty`, and that each commit added a new file.

There is an option to change this behavior for git-diff (https://github.com/git/git/commit/90d43b07687fdc51d1f2fc14948df538dc45584b), but currently it is not exposed in an option to `git merge`.

The other merge strategies do not seem to give the desired behavior either.

Comment: Thanks -- useful info. The first link says "This will cause a modify/delete conflict on the merge, which will let the user sort it out themselves", which unfortunately isn't happening.

Comment: That is only if the empty file gets content added.  You can look at the test on the commit and see that behavior.